# Certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ngrok

Im running ngrok for development on a windows 7 machine. i installed conda to work with python 2.7 and first `pip` was not working it keeps throwing a certificate error. i "fixed" the `pip` install by download the package and running `setup.py`.

now the issue is that when i run ngrok i get the following error:

```
Tunnel Status                 reconnecting (x509: certificate signed by unknown authority)
Version                       2.1.3
Region                        United States (us)
```

im not sure what is wrong or how to go abut fixing this error on Windows 7.

Comment: Well the issue appears to be that whatever you're connecting to has an untrusted certificate, probably self-signed. Without further details of the certificate or what exactly you're connecting to, there's not much more detail we can provide.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sign that your network (likely a corporate network) is attempting to MITM the outbound TLS connection that the ngrok agent makes to the ngrok edge, which ngrok does not allow.